# Legacy LongRange Mode information (mode 1 in the my attached link)

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, noise, signal-detection, preamble

Mode 1- Legacy Long Range Packet Format and Im attaching a photo of ti reference:
[image]

link for more information about this mode category : [TI SWRA642](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra642/swra642.pdf)

I want to understand the packet format, what's my syncword Data in HEXA that this legacy mode use? , what's the payload length in this mode? I didn't understand what's N and DSSS symbols that are found in multiplication sum for length of payload: N*8*DSS symbols...what should its values? could you guys please explain and illustrate all those parameters of mode 1 by an example of transmitted packet with explaining its transmitted data and how it looks once transmitted? thanks alot!

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Welcome. This question is very standard-specific. Maybe https://e2e.ti.com/ is a better place.